# Conditional Deployment in Arquillian

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

Looking at the Arquillian documentation, I am aware that I can use the @ArquillianSuiteDeployment and @Deployment annotations to deploy my desired jars/wars to the container. Example:

```
@ArquillianSuiteDeployment
public class MyDeployer {

    @Deployment(name = "myapp", order = 1, testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> myDeploymentJar() {
        final File file = Maven.configureResolver().fromFile(System.getProperty("settings.xml"))
            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve("com.myapp:test-app").withoutTransitivity()
            .asSingleFile();
        final JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(JavaArchive.class, file);
        final JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test-app.jar").merge(jar);
        return archive;
    }
}
```

Let's infer that I have two more jars that I would like to deploy, but never  together during the same test, JAR-A and JAR-C.

```
@Test
@RunAsClient
public void testOne() {
    // deploy JAR-A before all others, but do not deploy JAR-C
}

@Test
@RunAsClient
public void testTwo() {
    // deploy JAR-C before all others, but do not deploy JAR-A
}
```

Is it possible to introduce a conditional @Deployment that would go along with my tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting usecase.

Deployments happen before execution of the tests so it's not possible at the moment to achieve it just by using annotations.

You can, however, programmatically control deployments using `Deployer` service.

```
@Deployment(name = "JAR-C", managed = false)
public static WebArchive create() {
  return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class);
}

@ArquillianResource
private Deployer deployer;

@Test
public void should_work() {
  deployer.deploy("JAR-C");
  // test
  deploy.undeploy("JAR-C");
}
```

Important fact is that you have to instruct Arquillian to not manage this deployment for you, that's what `managed = false` flag is for in `@Deployment(name = "X", managed = false)`.

Hope that helps.